# Failed to download an image file from my node js server through my frontend (my backend and frontend are decoupled)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pipe, response

My nodejs backend is running on localhost:8080 and frontend on localhost:8081 using http-server, I am not able to download file from my server side to client side, I am new to node js so facing some problems with it

What I tried

I created a readstream to my required file on server side and then pipe it to res object , also I set some headers :-

```
res.setHeader("Content-Type","image/png") // as I am trying to download a 
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `inline; filename=${filename}`);
```

But it still fails

Code:-

code for downloading a file from server side

```
let filename = "hello.png";
let readStream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "..", chatDoc.chatContent));
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png")
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `inline; filename=${filename}`);
readStream.pipe(res);
```

cors code:-

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:8081",
    credentials: true,
    withCredentials: true
}))
```

frontend code:-

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/downloadNow",{
    method:"POST",
    headers:{
      "Content-Type":"application/json"
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({
      chatId:chatId
    }),
    credentials:"include"
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

Response on frontend:-
I got successfully response from server but file isn't downloaded.

[image]

please help me out with this

Comment: No, this question does not resolve my problem

Comment: @BHANUARORA — It really looks like it does. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274086/19068 in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that all of your servercode handling the download? If yes, you are not waiting for the `readStream` to properly open. And you should also add proper error handling, when the readStream couldn't be opened. Use

```
let readStream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "..", chatDoc.chatContent));
readStream.on("open", () => {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type","image/png")
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `inline; filename=${filename}`);
  readStream.pipe(res);
})
readStream.on("error", e => {
  console.log(e);
  res.writeHead(400);
});
```

And to download a file with `fetch`(in my understanding this means saving the file to disk instead of displaying it in the browser) you nonetheless need to apply the means of the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545632/how-can-i-download-a-file-using-window-fetch) ...

Comment: thanks, my code worked now , but there is a small problem with your server side code you should write  readstream.pipe(res), edit it and then I will mark this as correct

Comment: @BHANUARORA Yes, you are right. I swapped that in a hurry ...

Answer (score 0):

### Try this one

### Server

```
let mime = {
  html: 'text/html',
  txt: 'text/plain',
  css: 'text/css',
  gif: 'image/gif',
  jpg: 'image/jpeg',
  png: 'image/png',
  svg: 'image/svg+xml',
  js: 'application/javascript'
};
app.post('/imageDownload', async(req, res) => {
  var type = mime[path.extname(req.body.imagePath).slice(1)] || 
  'text/plain';
  var s = fs.createReadStream(file);
  s.on('open', function () {
   res.set('Content-Type', type);
   s.pipe(res);
  });
  s.on('error', function (err) {
   console.log(err)
   res.send(err)
  });
}
```

### Client

```
fetch(`/imageDownload`,{ 
   method: 'POST',
   headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
   },
   body:JSON.stringify({
      imagePath:url
   }),
 }).then(response => response.blob())
   .then(function(myBlob) {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([myBlob]));
         const link = document.createElement('a');
         link.href = url;
         link.setAttribute('download', "filename.jpg"); 
         document.body.appendChild(link);
         link.click();
  })
```

Comment: That looks to be the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274086/19068) which the OP said did not solve their problem.